# Defining a function in neighborhoods of points

Tags: function-construction

I want to define a function `g[s]` such that `g[s_]:=f[s]` in a (arbitrarily small open) neighborhood around `s1` and `g[s_]:=0` in a (arbitrarily small open) neighborhood around `s2`.

How do I do that?  It looks like Piecewise requires actual numbers to be inputted, but I don't have numerical values of `s1` and `s2`, so I don't think I can use that.

The goal would be to get it so that, for example,

```
Derivative[n][g][s1]==Derivative[n][f][s1]
Derivative[n][g][s2]==0
```

Edit: In the meantime I've been able to mimic a solution with

```
g0[s_] := f[s];

g[s1] = g0[s1];
g[s2] = 0;
Derivative[n_][g][s1] := Derivative[n][g0][s1]
Derivative[n_][g][s2] := 0
```